# How can I align the radio buttons horizontally?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lightning-radiogroup

> `<lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup" label="Radio Group" options={shippingOptions} value={shippingValue} type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>`

This outputs the radio buttons on top of each other (in a column) but I am expecting something like this. [image]

Can it be done?

Comment: It seem like a duplicate of: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342052/im-trying-to-display-radio-group-horizontally-in-lwc-but-it-seems-to-be-not-ap
As a variant you can make custom radio buttons as answered in the link above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to display Radio Group horizontally in lwc, but it seems to be not applying my custom css](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342052/im-trying-to-display-radio-group-horizontally-in-lwc-but-it-seems-to-be-not-ap)